# Require a json file within angularjs using nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs

I am using NodeJS and AngularJS.

Within Angular I would like to reference a json file and seperate parts of the json into different controllers.

At the moment I am using http.get within the controller (see below).

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('introCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('src/data_json.js').success(function(data) {
    $scope.intro = data;
});
```

This returns the entire json object within my first controller. However I would like to require the json file, store it as a variable, and have multiple controllers reference different parts.

Is there a way to use nodejs to pass the json file to the angular controller Or is there a better way to require the json file using angular?

Many thanks

Comment: Once you get the json in angular app you can communicate that json to other controllers using angular services

Answer (score 1):

A good strategy would be store the http request in a service [Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services). Then you can made that service avaible to all your controllers by simply inject it.

If your using a `REST` service you should also consider to use [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I used a factory service in the end like you suggested...

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

// Setting up a service to house our json file so that it can be called by the controllers
App.factory('service', function($http) {
    var promise;
    var jsondata = {
        get: function() {
            if ( !promise ) {
                var promise =  $http.get('src/data_json.js').success(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
                return promise;
            }
        }
    };
    return jsondata;
});




App.controller('introCtrl', function (service , $scope) {
    service.get().then(function(d) {
        $scope.header = d.data.PACKAGE.ITEM[0]
    })
});

App.controller('secondCtrl', function (service , $scope) {
    service.get().then(function(d) {
        $scope.title = d.data.PACKAGE.ITEM[1]
    })
});
```